# cannot replace diacritics ( ّ) sign in arabic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot replace diacritics `( ّ)` sign in Arabic, but I can replace the letter Arabic.

Here is I can replace Letter `م`

```
select REPLACE(mRoot.Name,N'م','') as Name
from ArabRootModels mRoot
where mRoot.Name=N'يُمَّ'
```

But when I tried to replace diacritics `( ّ)` sign it does not replace it.

Here is the code

```
select REPLACE(mRoot.Name,N' ّ','') as Name
from ArabRootModels mRoot
where mRoot.Name=N'يُمَّ'
```

Is there any problem with my code to replace with diacritics?

Comment: The data type for column `Name` in database table `ArabRootModels` is `NVARCHAR`, isn't it ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2018

Comment: According to the documentation for function [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): _REPLACE performs comparisons based on the collation of the input. To perform a comparison in a specified collation, you can use COLLATE to apply an explicit collation to the input._

Comment: +1 Interesting question. For most other languages you can just slap something like   `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and call it a day. I don't think you can do that with Arabic. I thought your replace would work since the diacritics in Arabic are just combining characters.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it.....use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI`

```
SELECT (CAST(mRoot.Name AS VARCHAR(50)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI) AS Name
from ArabRootModels mRoot
where mRoot.Name=N'يُمَّ'
```

**For E.g.**

```
SELECT 'àéê!' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

**Result:-aee!**

**Note:- If your data type is Nvarchar cast into varchar(50)**

Comment: thanks i have tried yout code select (CAST(mRoot.Name AS VARCHAR(50)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI) AS Name
from ArabRootModels mRoot
where mRoot.Name=N'يُمَّ'
but i get result ?????